# GSM1: No answer, put_command expected (OK)|(ERROR)|(0)|(4)

Tags: pi-3, wiring, gsm

[`smstools3`](http://smstools3.kekekasvi.com/)'s `/var/log/smsd.log` keeps giving:

```
GSM1: Checking if modem is ready
GSM1: -> AT
GSM1: Command is sent, waiting for the answer. (5)
GSM1: No answer, put_command expected (OK)|(ERROR)|(0)|(4), timeout occurred. 1.
```

My `/etc/smsd.conf`:

```
# Example smsd.conf. Read the manual for a description

devices = GSM1
logfile = /var/log/smsd.log
loglevel = 7

[GSM1]
device = /dev/ttyAMA0
incoming = no
#pin = 1111
```

My `/boot/config.txt` contains:

```
[GSM modem on GPIO 14/15]
enable_uart=1
dtoverlay=miniuart-bt
```

What is causing this? I've tried a few different wiring configurations, and I still get the same error:
[image: wiring #1]

and the simpler

[image: wiring #2]

([*mutatis muntandis*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mutatis_mutandis#Adverb))

Comment: This question is lacking detail and any diagnostics. If it really is RS232 connecting to a Pi serial port won't work. Why would you nobble the Pi Bluetooth - this just an unnecessary complication and the default would be orders of magnitude faster than GSM.

Comment: @Milliways "_lacking detail and any diagnostics_" What detail would help the post? "_If it really is RS232 connecting to a Pi serial port won't work._" What do I connect it to, then? "_Why would you nobble the Pi Bluetooth_" I saw somewhere in the documentation that is necessary, because Bluetooth uses the those same pins.

Comment: @Milliways "_the default would be orders of magnitude faster than GSM._" What's the default? Aren't I supposed to be using GSM with a GSM modem?

Comment: Why would you believe what you "saw somewhere" rather than the official documentation https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#configuring-uarts or the numerous posts on this site.

Comment: @Milliways I saw it on some RaspberryPi.com documentation page.

Comment: @Milliways Should my device be `/dev/ttyAMA0` or `/dev/ttyS0`?

Comment: Neither. See [How do I make serial work on the Raspberry Pi3 or later](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45571/8697) Bluetooth  definitely  DOESN'T  "uses the those same pins"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150673/discussion-between-geremia-and-milliways).